# Informatica Powercenter Designer Import Tables. The specified DSN contains an architecture mismatch between the Driver and Application

Tags: oracle, client, informatica

I am using Informatica Powercenter Designer and specifying my Source, which is an Oracle database. I clicked on the Source -> Import Tables and typed in the database user name and password. I specified the Oracle ODBC driver (Oracle in OraClient11g_home). It gives me the following error

[Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] The specified DSN contains an architecture mismatch between the Driver and Application.

Early I configure the ODBC driver for Oracle and used the same username and worked. I click Test Connection and it was successful.

When I typed in the user name, the Owner name auto populates with the same username.

I am not sure what the error means or how to fix it to see the tables in the Powercenter Source Designer.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to use a 32-bit ODBC driver with a 64-bit Informatica, or vice-versa. The application architecture must match that of the DSN.

If you are using a 64-bit version of windows, then the default is for it to use the 64-bit version of the ODBC administrator. To access the 32-bit version use:

c:\windows\sysWOW64\odbcad32.exe
And set up your DSN here.